# Tidy eval: Evaluation of quosure in function within map

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyeval

I am trying to write a function that makes use of an object's name (as in unevaluated symbol) for downstream application. Here is an example that captures the sense:

```
return_obj_name <- function(obj){
  inp <- enquo(obj)
 
  inp_name <- rlang::as_name(inp) # Use the name for something
  inp_data <- rlang::eval_tidy(inp) # This line just for completeness, not important here
  
  return(inp_name)
}
```

Here is a standard use case of this function:

```
test_obj <- 42
return_obj_name(test_obj)

[1] "test_obj"
```

So far, so good. However, I plan to use my function as an anonymous function in a map (or map2) statement, and this is where things go wrong.

```
test_obj2 <- 44
test_vec <- c(test_obj, test_obj2)
map(test_vec, ~ .x %>% return_obj_name())

[[1]]
[1] "."

[[2]]
[1] "."
```

The intended output would have been:

```
[[1]]
[1] "test_obj"

[[2]]
[1] "test_obj2"
```

I think I do understand what is happening. The function receives the piped reference to the initial object, which would be ".". It quotes this with enquo and continues as by design.

I am wondering if there is a way to with evaluate the reference in the environment in which map is called, as opposed to within the map call, as is happening now.

Comment: and why do yu need this? Whats the purpose? Check `imap` if you are interested at the names

Comment: What do you mean "why do I need it?"? Isn't the question enough as is? I don't want names, I want the deparsed, quoted symbol.

Comment: the issue is 42 and 44 are not NAMES but rather VALUES. eg what if you had dataframes? Do you want the whole dataframe to be the NAME?

Comment: The intended output of 42 and 44 is confusing - I believe your line of ```inp_data``` would return that if you are interested in the values. If you are instead interested in ```test_obj``` and ```test_obj2```, I am not sure that those are recoverable - I do not believe ```test_vec``` would still know about it's origins as this example is constructed.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I fixed the output.

Comment: The magrittr pipe works by data-masking `.` and passing that value to the piped function. It is fully expected to see `.` if you defuse the piped argument.

Answer (score 3):

After you run

```
test_obj2 <- 44
test_vec <- c(test_obj, test_obj2)
```

The value `test_vec` has no knowledge of the names of the variables that were used to create it. All it knows is that it's a numeric vector that contains 42 and 44. Tracking the source for every variable would create a lot of overhead.

It's important to remember that values do not have names in R; it's the names that have values. And it's not always unique either. Multiple names can point to the same value.

In addition, the pipe operator does not preserve variable names. Observe

```
test_obj %>% return_obj_name()
# [1] "."
```

If you want to keep track of labels for value sources, you should either use a named list (but remember, it's the collection that tracks the names, the elements in the collection are unaware if they are named) or have a separate vector of names. The answer given by @Ronak offers some good alternatives using this strategy.

Another alternative would be to store your values as a collection of quosures. For example

```
test_vec <- quos(test_obj, test_obj2)
map(test_vec, ~return_obj_name(!!.x))
```

But here `test_vec` is storing those variable names, and not their necessarily their values. You would need to evaluate it to get the values 42 and 44.

Answer (score 2):

The stand-alone example that you have shared does not match with the `map` intended output. In the stand-alone example you run `return_obj_name(test_obj)` and get output as `"test_obj"`. Note that here the value of `"test_obj"` is 42. But in the `map` example your intended output is to return `"42"` and `"44"` instead of `test_obj` and `test_obj2` ? One of this needs to change for the question to be consistent.

Anyway, as far as answer is concerned I think you should name your vector/list explicitly and pass that as separate object.

```
return_obj_name <- function(obj, name){
   #Do something
   #Do something
   return(name)
}
```

For example, using `tibble::lst` which makes it easy to name objects.

```
test_vec <- tibble::lst(test_obj, test_obj2)
```

You can then use `imap` :

```
purrr::imap(test_vec, return_obj_name)
#$test_obj
#[1] "test_obj"

#$test_obj2
#[1] "test_obj2"
```

Or `Map` in base R :

```
Map(return_obj_name, test_vec, names(test_vec))
```

If you want to return `"42"` and `"44"` i.e the values here that would be `obj` value in `return_obj_name` function.